# Is the inverse of a fractional ideal still fractional?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ the field of fractions of $R$, $\mathfrak{m}$ be a fractional ideal of $R$, i.e. a non-zero finitely generated $R$-submodule of $K$. We define
$$\mathfrak{m}^{-1}:=\{y\in K: y\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R\}$$

> I want to prove that $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$ is a fractional ideal.

For every $y\in\mathfrak{m}^{-1}, r\in R$, we have $ry\in\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$, which ensures that $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$ is an $R$-submodule of $K$.

Let $x\in\mathfrak{m},x\neq 0$. Then $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}x\subseteq R$, by definition of $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$, so that $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}\subseteq x^{-1}R$, but $x^{-1}R$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, $R$ is noetherian, hence $x^{-1}R$ is noetherian (as a module), so $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$ is finitely generated, as a sub-module of a noetherian module.

In order to have $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$ fractional ideal, i need $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}\neq 0$. How can i prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated, you can find a generating family $\frac {a_1}{b_1}, \ldots, \frac {a_n}{b_n} \in \mathfrak m$. 
Now, let $c = b_1b_2 \ldots b_n$. Forall $i$, $c\frac {a_i}{b_i} \in R$, and so forall $m \in \mathfrak m, cm \in R$. Hence $c \in \mathfrak m^{-1}$

Comment: oh, yes, a common denominator, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$, for every non-zero $a\in K$, there is a non-zero $b\in R$ such that $ba\in R$. We are assuming $\mathfrak{m}\neq 0$, so let $a$ be a non-zero element. Then its corresponding element $b$ must be in $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}$. Hence, $\mathfrak{m}^{-1}\neq 0$.

Comment: you say that $ba\in R$, but how can i know that $bx\in R$ for every $x\in\mathfrak{m}$?